# JNI: How to get class of jdoubleArray as a 'jclass' on the JNI/C++ side?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface, native-methods

I wrote a *native* Java function that passes a 2D array of double. What is a "double [][]" on the Java side, becomes a "jobjectArray" on the JNI/C++ side. So I need to use **GetObjectArrayElement()** to access the elements of the "outer" array, and these elements (i.e. the "inner" arrays) **should** be of type *jdoubleArray*. But I get them, from the *GetObjectArrayElement()* function, as *jobject* type. Now, how do I check whether the *jobject* is actually a *jdoubleArray* using the **IsInstanceOf()** function?

I obviously need a *jclass* that represents the *jobjectArray* class. But how to do that? I have *no* idea what *string* I would need to pass to **FindClass** for the *jobjectArray* class. Apparently, there's no equivalent for the *jobjectArray* on the Java side... The only method that I have figured out so far is:

```
jdoubleArray dummyDoubleArray = env->NewDoubleArray(1);
jclass doubleArrayClass = env->GetObjectClass(dummyDoubleArray);

if(env->IsInstanceOf(element, doubleArrayClass)) ...
```

This needs to create a dummy DoubleArray every time! Is there a more efficient way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, it seems we can simply use `FindClass("[D")` here...

Comment: Why do you need to check? If the parameter to the JNI method is `double[][]`, that's all it can be.

Comment: I don't think so. On the C++/JNI side all I get is a generic "jobjectArray" pointer, so this could by an array of whatever. It would be safe to assume we got an array of the proper type, if the actual argument type was encoded in the symbolic function name. But it isn't. The C++ function name is "Java_packageName_className_methodName" and that's it. So a *native* function, defined as "myFunction(double [][] arg)" on the Java-side would have the exactly same C++ name as, for example, "myFunction(float [][] arg)" or "myFunction(int [][] arg)". Thus, I need to make sure it's the right type.